# The scrollable height is ignoring the bottom margin of the last child of a scrollable div in Safari/Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

```css
.scroll {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keLx9wb6/)

The above snippet consists of a scrollable div of size 200px. Inside that is an element with height 100%, and inside that is another element with height 100% but with top and bottom margin of 50px.

I would expect that the scrollable height of the div would be 50 + 200 + 50 = 300px. Indeed, this is the case in Chrome and Firefox where you can see the top and bottom yellow margin when you scroll the div, but for some reason Safari clips the bottom margin and the scrollable height is only 50 + 200 = 250px.

Who is correct here? Is this a Safari bug? Is there an easy fix for this without changing the overall structure of the page too much?

Comment: Tried to reproduce it and just wanted to confirm that I see this happening too in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: auto;` to your `div.inner` seems to solve the problem in Safari.

```css
.scroll {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however this just changes the structure of the DOM so that there is no non-scrollable intermediate div, which is what the original problem has. A div immediately inside a scrollable div doesn't have this problem (as you have shown), but that is not the issue.